# HTML5 Video Not Loading

Tags: css, html, video

I am currently learning to use videos as a background on the websites I am developing. The issue that I am having is that I can't get the videos to actually appear. I believe it has to do with the way I have them stored in a folder, but after trying multiple different methods of accessing the files, I still can't get them to display. The goal is to have the video stored in the "videos" folder to be displayed as my page background. My question is, what elements am I missing for this to work? I have tried moving the files into the main folder as well as adjusting the CSS a few times. Both yielded no results.

My current setup is as followed:

My files are stored like this (I apologize for the link, I can't embed images yet):
[File Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbHQ2.png)

```css
backgroundVideo {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: URL(images/resBackground.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <video autoplay loop class="backgroundVideo">
        <source src="videos/resVideoBackground.mp4" type="videos/mp4"/>Your browser does not support the video tag! Please upgrade your broswer!
        <source src="videos/resVideoBackground.webm" type="videos/webm"/>Your browser does not support the video tag! Please upgrade your broswer!
        <source src="videos/resVideoBackground.ogv" type="videos/ogv"/>Your browser does not support the video tag! Please upgrade your broswer!
      </video>

</body>
```

Any guidance on how to get the video running is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note: to reference to a class in css you should use `.backgroundVideo` with the `.`

Comment: can you link us to your site? do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: The current site I am working on is hosted locally, I am not receiving any errors in the console at this point. @MichaelCoker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file hierarchy and the way you are referencing your files from your CSS and HTML looks fine to me.

I notice a couple things right off the bat. The first is that, in your `source` elements, the proper type is a singular `video/mp4`, `video/webm`, and `video/ogv`.

Another common tactic when implementing background videos into websites is to add a little JavaScript that "kicks" them on browsers that don't like the `autoplay` attribute. For example (you'll need to add an `id="backgroundVideo"` to your video element for this to work):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Play the background video on Android devices that support the
    // "canplay" event listener
    var backgroundVideo= document.getElementById('backgroundVideo');
    backgroundVideo.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
        backgroundVideo.play();
    });
</script>
```

I would add this script element, either externally or inline, at the very end of the body.

Comment: So you suggest only having one source tag with either `video/mp4`,`video/webm`, or `video/ogv`? Or are you saying have all three with the same type? Also, I created a scripts.js file and linked it using `<script src="scripts.js"></script>` right before the closing body tag. Is this what you suggested? @Treebasher

Comment: @Japur not exactly. It is good to have multiple `source` elements of multiple different types so that the browser can choose which one it supports best. I was simply saying that there is a type in each of your `source` element's `type` parameters in that `video` should not be plural (you have `videos` in all three).

And yes, that is what I suggested :)